# Get Android Auto notification to launch auto app when clicked - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-auto

I have an Android mobile app with Auto support, and when in Java, the auto app was working fine to launch the auto app when the notification was clicked.

However, since I've migrated everything to kotlin I only have one remaining issue.  The notification in Auto does not want to let me open the auto app, unless I've already started the app first. Then, it seems to work fine until I start over, and it's the same error.

I can launch the auto app directly from the launcher in auto without a problem.

The logs are sparse and vague. In Android Auto when clicking my notification, I get:
"Android Auto has encountered an unexpected error" and the only relevant logs I can find are below.

It seems like there's some type of dynamic binding of the service class name which is incorrect?

I'm referring to the differences in the logs like "com.lusion.sgauto/.SGService" vs "com.lusion.sgauto/com.lusion.sgauto.SGService"

```
CarApp.H.Tem: Intent to bind to car app service Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10 cmp=com.lusion.sgauto/.SGService (has extras) }
CarApp.H.Tem: Binding to: com.lusion.sgauto/.SGService

D CarApp.H: Fragment does not have a context, will return an empty surface provider, detached: false
W PackageManager: Intent does not match component's intent filter: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW id=0/main flg=0x10 cmp=com.lusion.sgauto/.SGService (has extras) }
W PackageManager: Access blocked: ComponentInfo{com.lusion.sgauto/com.lusion.sgauto.SGService}
W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW id=0/main flg=0x10 cmp=com.lusion.sgauto/.SGService (has extras) } U=0: not found
CarApp.H.Tem: Error: [type: null, cause: null, debug msg: Failed to bind to ComponentInfo{com.lusion.sgauto/com.lusion.sgauto.SGService}]
```

I have the service registered in androidmanifest.xml as

```
<service
    android:name=".SGService"
    android:exported="true"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
        <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.IOT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My notification builder looks like this

```
.extend(
    CarAppExtender.Builder()
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle!!)
        .setContentIntent(
            CarPendingIntent.getCarApp(
                context.applicationContext, 0,
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setComponent(
                    ComponentName(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        SGService::class.java
                    )
                ), 0
            )
        )
        .addAction(icon1, title1, autoPendingIntent1!!)
        .addAction(icon2, title2, autoPendingIntent2!!)
        .setImportance(importance).build()
)
```

The service is defined like below

```
class SGService : CarAppService() {
    private var garageUpdateThread: Thread? = null
    override fun onCreateSession(): Session {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateSession")
        initNotifications(this)
        try {
            this.registerReceiver(
                uiMessageBroadcastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(R.string.local_main_activity_listener.toString())
            )
            registerBroadcastReceiver()
        }
        catch (e:java.lang.Exception)
        {
            // already registered
        }
        ongoingGarageStatusThread(applicationContext, "SGService")
        return object : Session() {
            override fun onCreateScreen(intent: Intent): Screen {
                return SGScreen(carContext)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedRegisterReceiverFlag")
    private fun registerBroadcastReceiver() {
        Log.i(TAG, "registerBroadcastReceiver")
        val filter = IntentFilter("com.lusion.sgauto.SGService")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            applicationContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
        }
        else
            applicationContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter)

    }

    private val mBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

            val responseType: LusionUtility.UpdateType? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                intent.getSerializableExtra("TYPE", LusionUtility.UpdateType::class.java)
            } else {
                intent.getSerializableExtra("TYPE") as LusionUtility.UpdateType
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "SGService BroadcastReceiver $responseType")
            if (responseType != null) {
                if (responseType == LusionUtility.UpdateType.GARAGESTATUS) {
                    var garageStatus: GarageStatus?
                    try {
                        garageStatus = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                            intent.getSerializableExtra(responseType.toString(), GarageStatus::class.java)
                        } else {
                            intent.getSerializableExtra(responseType.toString()) as GarageStatus?
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        garageStatus = GarageStatus.UNKNOWN
                        Log.e(TAG, "SGScreen mBroadcastReceiver received unknown garage status")
                    }
                    // only if garage status has changed will we update the screen
                    if (garageStatus !== autoGarageStatus) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "triggerNotification $garageStatus")
                        //                        LusionUtility.triggerNotification(getCarContext(), "GARAGESTATUS", garageStatus);
                        autoGarageStatus = garageStatus
                    }
                    // Move this invalidate to SGScreen broadcast receiver
                    val relayIntent = Intent("com.lusion.sgauto.SGScreen")
                    relayIntent.putExtras(intent)
                    Log.i(TAG, "SGService send intent com.lusion.sgauto.SGScreen")
                    context.sendBroadcast(relayIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All of the details are in the posted question